# How do I reset my footer.php to its original state? (theme: Origami)

Tags: code, footer, customization, reset

I accidentally deleted some codes from my footer.php trying to get rid of the 'Theme By Origami' footer, and now the footer is all messed up. How do i reset it to its original state?
I feel so stupid, I should have backed up the text before deleting it, Im so careless..

My website: http://www.agnesphotoandfilm.co.uk/
My theme: Origami

please help

Answer (score 1):

Download the theme-- actually download to your computer rather than use the built in updater/installer--, unzip it, find the footer file, and upload that to your [site over FTP](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients).

After that, my advice would be to [setup a development environment on your computer](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20development%20environment) and don't edit the live site directly.

Comment: If this solved the question please mark it as "Accepted". Look for the check mark on the left.